# Full Image of internal HDD, drive - dd / dd_rescue - with TrueCrypt [bad sectors] [read error]

Tags: dd, disk-image, badblocks, ddrescue, truecrypt

**Background**

I had a problem under Windows with ndis.sys [sys don't start]
*Status: 0xc00000e9
Info: Windows failed to load because a critical system driver...*
To repair I had to fully decrypt drive [encrypted with TrueCrypt]. 
Encryption was running fine, but at some point it found a bad sector.

[image]

At some point it slowed down decryption process significantly. As I was thinking it's a disk problem - I did a search and came across  - option to do a full drive backup with Linux **dd** command. That supposed to give me image of whole HDD drive in case of ongoing corruption and possibility to run decryption from different drive.

Lenovo G500s

[image: to rescue sda]

**What I did so far**

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/usb
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/usb
sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt/usb
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/usb/image.dd conv=noerror
```

The result being

```
dd: error reading '/dev/sda': Input/output error
254256+0 records in
254256+0 records out
```

I have just noticed I can do image trough Disks [I work on latest Knoppix DVD], but didn't try it yet.
Also I was getting suggestions that I can use dd_rescue, but has heard it is not exactly safe to the data on drive as it over-writes bad blocks? And didn't try it yet.

I'm stuck, please help, I don't have a full backup of latest work from my sys partition, although seems that sda3 / sda5 was fully decrypted.

Comment: Please note that `ddrescue` is a tool distinct from `dd`. `ddrescue` is also better at dealing with marginal media; `conv=noerror` simply skips unreadable blocks in the input when writing to the output, but that messes up offsets. You should be using `ddrescue` on any marginal or potentially marginal media.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about `ddrescue`.
It doesn't over-write bad blocks. Who told that this program is unsafe, they got rescued bad sector not the same it was be. But if bad sector is corrupted it has corrupted data and the ddrescue program tryes to read this sector several times and gives each time different data. This program uses average of different data to try to rescue them. Many of rescued bad sectors have wrong data.

Full rescue is possible only from backup. RAID isn't backup. But it allows you quickly replace bad disk and restore functionality.

You can find good example of using ddrescue at  http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Ddrescue